# Const pass = "passwordkey" in ThisWorkbook... can this be referenced in Userforms, Sheets, and Modules?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on some VBA code written by another individual within Excel. They created a

```
Const pass = "passwordkey"
```

in ThisWorkbook.

Can I reference this in a userform code, another sheet code, or module code? If yes, how?

I am wanting to essentially do this in the areas mentioned:

```
ActiveWorkbook.UnProtect (pass)
```

*(but it is not working...)*

Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Public` keyword. `Public Const pass = "passwordkey"`

Edit: I just noticed you said this was in `ThisWorkbook`. You cannot use the public keyword there. You need to place this in a standard module

> ### [Scope of variables in Visual Basic for Applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/141693/scope-of-variables-in-visual-basic-for-applications)
>
> **Summary**
>   The scope of a variable is determined at the time the variable is declared. In Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications, the three scopes available for variables are procedure, module, and public. The "More Information" section of this article describes each scope in detail.
>
> **Public scope**
>   Public variables have the broadest scope of all variables. A public variable is recognized by every module in the active workbook. To make a public variable available to other workbooks, from a new workbook select the workbook containing the public variable in the Available References box of the References dialog box (from a module sheet, click References on the Tools menu).
>
> A public variable, like a module-level variable, is declared at the top of the module, above the first procedure definition. A public variable cannot be declared within a procedure. A public variable is always declared with a "Public" statement. A public variable may be declared in any module sheet.
>
> It is possible for multiple module sheets to have public variables with the same name. To avoid confusion and possible errors, it is a good idea to use unique names or to precede each variable name with a module qualifier (for example, in a module named "Feb_Sales" you may want to precede all public variables with the letters "FS").

Comment: Hi K. Davis- thanks for your response! Will I have to create a sub and call it in ThisWorkbook, as well as the Userforms and Sheets code? Or can I simply create a module containing the `Public Const pass = "passwordkey"` and reference the module and pass? (I am still what I would call a basic user and want to get the best practices down!)

Comment: No, you just need to create a standard module and place that line there. It will work for your **entire** project.

Comment: Okay I'll give that a try. Once it is in there, the other modules, sheets, etc know to reference it? (They are constantly checking for such public variables?) Thank you again!

Comment: @mitchmitch24 Yes. If you would have used the `Private` keyword, then the variable would only be in the module that contains the variable. And it's not that it's "constantly checking", it does this before runtime.

Comment: Awesome. It worked. Thank you for the help and explanations. Super valuable!